# Браузер сохраняет, но не отправляет куки

Tags: ajax, веб-программирование, http, cookie

Здравствуйте.

Проблема возникает следующая: отправляю запрос на авторизацию через AJAX. Передаю данные пользователя. Сервер в ответ отправляет статус выполнения задачи в формате JSON и передает куку с ID сессии.

Сам запрос:

```
$.ajax({
        type:   "POST",
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        data:   "login="+Login+"&password="+Password+"&code="+FA2Code,
        url:        "/dashboard/api/auth",

        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#load-indicator').show();
        },

        success:        function(data) {
            $('#load-indicator').hide();
            if ( data.code == 201 ) {
                $("div#fa2").fadeIn(2000);
                return;
            }

    if ( data.code == 200 ) {
      window.location = "/dashboard/home/";
    }
        }
    })
```

Браузер куку сохранил. Я ее вижу в хранилище и данные переданы верно. НО! При редиректе на страницу /dashboard/home/ кука не отдается. Не могу понять в чем моя ошибка, подскажите?

Дополнительно:
Кука сессионная (если не установлен флаг "Запомнить меня"), иначе сохраняется на 24 часа.

Вид заголовков после успешной авторизации:
[image: Отправляемые заголовки после успешной авторизации]

Кука сохранена и браузер ее видит:
[image: Сохраненная кука сразу после атворизации]

Comment: Дополните вопрос скрином установленной куки.

Comment: открываете консоль разработчика (хром F12). Идете в таб network. Делаете свой запрос и смотрите на данные которые вы отсылаете и которые приходят.

Comment: Кука приходит вместе с ответом на AJAX запрос, однако, после перенаправления на главную страницу по условию JS сценария кука не отправляется. Тем не менее, браузер хранит эту куку, сессия на сервер открыта.

Answer (score 2):

Куку следует устанавливать для пути `/`, чтобы она была видна на всем сайте. У вас же (по скрину вижу) кука установлена только для `/dashboard/api/`.

P.S. Так же в обязательном порядке при отправке куки с сервера установите флаг **HttpOnly** в `true`, иначе любой скрипт может скопировать ее содержимое.